# Get Param from .htaccess in angularjs + ui-router

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, angular-ui-router

My app is a multi-language (`angular-translate`) `angularjs` app with `ui-router`. And I am having a problem getting the parameter from the `.htaccess` redirect.

## What I want is the following routing.

- `www.example.com/en` = The English version.
- `www.example.com/he` = The Hebrew version.
- `www.example.com/ar` = The Arabic version.
- Anything else redirected to the English version.

## On the Client Side

my `app.config` looks like this:

> Language State

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/:lang',
    template: '<sh-app/>',
    controller: function ($translate, $state, $rootScope) {
        $translate.use($state.params.lang);

        if (/he|ar/.test($state.params.lang)) {
            $rootScope.dir = 'rtl';
        }
    }
});
```

> Home State

```
$stateProvider.state('app.home', {
    url: '/',
    template: '<sh-main/>'
});
```

> And of course to remove the hashbang

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

## Now to the Server Side.

I added an `.htaccess` file, with the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /7for70/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

The problem is that if I try and navigate to `www.example.com/ar` it just redirects to `www.example.com/en/` and `$stateParams.lang === 'en'`.

How can I get the end of the url forwarded to ui-router.

Comment: https://swaac.tamouse.org/angularjs/2015/03/27/learning-ui-router-and-passing-values-in-$stateparams/

Comment: @Edison Interesting article, but doesn't solve my problem. In my Language State I am specifically defining the param in the url path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who ends up with the same problem, after two days of tearing my hears, I got an idea.

I appended a trailing slash to my url's like this:

- `www.example.com/en => www.example.com/en/`
- `www.example.com/he => www.example.com/he/`
- `www.example.com/ar => www.example.com/ar/`

and viola, it worked!

From there it was very easy to find the solution in the [ui-router docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-make-a-trailing-slash-optional-for-all-routes) to deal with the trailing slash.

> For older version of ui-router, add this snippet to your module's config function. It creates a rule on $urlRouterProvider that maps all urls that are missing a trailing slash to the same url but with the trailing slash appended.

```
$urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {
    var path = $location.url();

    // check to see if the path already has a slash where it should be
    if (path[path.length - 1] === '/' || path.indexOf('/?') > -1) {
        return;
    }

    if (path.indexOf('?') > -1) {
        return path.replace('?', '/?');
    }

    return path + '/';
});
```

---

## EDIT: (After ~20 minutes)

Seems like you need to add a trailing slash to the abstract state, and remove it from the rest.

So the abstract state is: `url: '/:lang/'`
And then the home state will be `url: ''`